# soap client return cannot destabilize the response body netcore

Tags: c#, asp.net, xml, soap

I have a dotnet app that consumes a SOAP service, the problem is when I call the service immediately return an exception said  ***cant read the resulting body***.

I tried to call the service through SOAP-UI, it worked very well.

below is the code was written to use the SOAP client.

```
        var request = new testRequest
        {
            moduleC = model.ModuleC.ToString(),
            moduleT = model.ModuleT.ToString(),
            Number = model.Number.ToString(),
        };
        var response = GetSoapResponse<TestRequest, TestResponse>((p) =>
        {
            var result = _client.TestMethod(request);
            return result;
        }, request);


private TResult GetSoapResponse<TParameters, TResult>(Func<TParameters, TResult> callback, TParameters parameters)
    {
        using (new OperationContextScope(_client.InnerChannel))
        {
            SetCredentials();
            var result = callback.Invoke(parameters);
            return result;
        }
    }

protected void SetCredentials() => OperationContext.Current.OutgoingMessageHeaders.Add(
                new UDBSecurityHeader(
                    Options.Username,
                    Options.Password));
```

And this is the code was generated from VS for the client :

```
[System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCodeAttribute("System.Xml", "4.8.3752.0")]
[System.SerializableAttribute()]
[System.Diagnostics.DebuggerStepThroughAttribute()]
[System.ComponentModel.DesignerCategoryAttribute("code")]
[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlTypeAttribute(AnonymousType=true, Namespace="http://www.sampple.com/test")]
public partial class TestResponse : object, System.ComponentModel.INotifyPropertyChanged {

    private TestResponseData dataField;

    private string statusCodeField;

    private string[] errorsField;

    private string isSucceedField;

    /// <remarks/>
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute(Order=0)]
    public TestResponseData data {
        get {
            return this.dataField;
        }
        set {
            this.dataField = value;
            this.RaisePropertyChanged("data");
        }
    }

    /// <remarks/>
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute(DataType="integer", Order=1)]
    public string statusCode {
        get {
            return this.statusCodeField;
        }
        set {
            this.statusCodeField = value;
            this.RaisePropertyChanged("statusCode");
        }
    }

    /// <remarks/>
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute("errors", Order=2)]
    public string[] errors {
        get {
            return this.errorsField;
        }
        set {
            this.errorsField = value;
            this.RaisePropertyChanged("errors");
        }
    }

    /// <remarks/>
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute(Order=3)]
    public string isSucceed {
        get {
            return this.isSucceedField;
        }
        set {
            this.isSucceedField = value;
            this.RaisePropertyChanged("isSucceed");
        }
    }

    public event System.ComponentModel.PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    protected void RaisePropertyChanged(string propertyName) {
        System.ComponentModel.PropertyChangedEventHandler propertyChanged = this.PropertyChanged;
        if ((propertyChanged != null)) {
            propertyChanged(this, new System.ComponentModel.PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
    }
}

public partial class TestResponseData : object, System.ComponentModel.INotifyPropertyChanged {

    private long permitSequenceField;

    private bool permitSequenceFieldSpecified;

    private long sequenceExceptionField;

    private bool sequenceExceptionFieldSpecified;

    private string statusField;

    public long permitSequence {
        get {
            return this.permitSequenceField;
        }
        set {
            this.permitSequenceField = value;
            this.RaisePropertyChanged("permitSequence");
        }
    }

    public bool permitSequenceSpecified {
        get {
            return this.permitSequenceFieldSpecified;
        }
        set {
            this.permitSequenceFieldSpecified = value;
            this.RaisePropertyChanged("permitSequenceSpecified");
        }
    }

    public long sequenceException {
        get {
            return this.sequenceExceptionField;
        }
        set {
            this.sequenceExceptionField = value;
            this.RaisePropertyChanged("sequenceException");
        }
    }

    public bool sequenceExceptionSpecified {
        get {
            return this.sequenceExceptionFieldSpecified;
        }
        set {
            this.sequenceExceptionFieldSpecified = value;
            this.RaisePropertyChanged("sequenceExceptionSpecified");
        }
    }

    public string status {
        get {
            return this.statusField;
        }
        set {
            this.statusField = value;
            this.RaisePropertyChanged("status");
        }
    }

    public event System.ComponentModel.PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    protected void RaisePropertyChanged(string propertyName) {
        System.ComponentModel.PropertyChangedEventHandler propertyChanged = this.PropertyChanged;
        if ((propertyChanged != null)) {
            propertyChanged(this, new System.ComponentModel.PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
    }
}
```

The expected XML response must be as the following:

```
<tns:TestResponse xmlns:tns="http://www.sampple.com/test">
     <tns:data>
        <tns:permitSequence>0.0</tns:permitSequence>
        <tns:sequenceException>0.0</tns:sequenceException>
        <tns:status>0</tns:status>
     </tns:data>
     <tns:statusCode>200</tns:statusCode>
     <tns:errors/>
     <tns:isSucceed>true</tns:isSucceed>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the data type that are return from the service are not allowed to mapped to the response for example if you have declared in response will return `long` and you are return `decimal` it couldn't be serialised from the response

```
private long permitSequenceField;

private long sequenceExceptionField;
```

the permitSequenceField and sequenceExceptionField are long you cant receive them as any another date type in xmlserializer

hope this solve your problem .

Comment: Thanks, The problem solved, but I'm wondering why may the code generator was confused when the entity created